# How to start crond as non-root user in a Docker Container?

Tags: docker, cron, centos

I am using the below `Dockerfile` and `entrypoint.sh`. I need to start the `crond` service in the container as a non-root user but I get `Permission denied`. How do I start the `crond` service as a non-root user?

I need have `USER` in `Dockerfile` as it is a mandatory admin setting in my Openshift 3 Platform.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM centos:centos7.4.1708
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y cronie && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN cd / && mkdir /code
ADD entrypoint.sh /code/
RUN chmod -R 755 /code/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/code/entrypoint.sh"]
RUN useradd -l -u 1001510000 -c "1001510000" 1001510000
USER 1001510000
CMD ["top"]
```

*entrypoint.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "in the entrypoint!"
echo "executing id"
id
echo "executing crond start"
crond start
echo "executing $@"
$@
```

*Error Output*

```
in the entrypoint!
executing id
uid=1001510000(1001510000) gid=1000(1001510000) groups=1000(1001510000)
executing crond start
crond: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied
executing top
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all `crond` has to invoke commands on behalf of other users. How could it do that without being run by `root`? Even if somehow you will run this demon process with this user there is a high probability that it will lack other permissions in order to run certain commands.

**But I guess you can try, maybe this will help:**

Your user simply doesn't have permissions as error log says. If you want to **try** run as non-root user create group lets say `crond-users` and change `/var/run/crond.pid` group from `root` to `crond-users`. Last but not least add your user to `crond-users` group.
Like so:

```
RUN groupadd crond-users && \
    chgrp crond-users /var/run/crond.pid && \
    usermod -a -G crond-users 1001510000
```

**Hitn 1**

Moreover, docker default entrypoint is `/bin/bash -c` but does not have a default command. So your Dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM centos:centos7.4.1708
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y cronie && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    cd / && mkdir /code && \
    chmod -R 755 /code/entrypoint.sh && \
    useradd -l -u 1001510000 -c "1001510000" 1001510000 && \
    addgroup crond-users && \
    chgrp crond-users /var/run/crond.pid && \
    usermod -a -G crond-users 1001510000

ADD entrypoint.sh /code/
USER 1001510000

CMD ["/code/entrypoint.sh", "top"]
```

**Hint 2.**

Try avoiding using multiple times the same Dockerfile instruction (In your case you had 4x RUN). Each instruction is a separate layer in later build image. This is known [Dockerfile best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

> Minimize the number of layers In older versions of Docker, it was
>   important that you minimized the number of layers in your images to
>   ensure they were performant. The following features were added to
>   reduce this limitation:
>
> In Docker 1.10 and higher, only the instructions RUN, COPY, ADD create
>   layers. Other instructions create temporary intermediate images, and
>   do not directly increase the size of the build.

Comment: `/var/run/crond.pid` is not created until `crond start` is executed, 
so `chgrp crond-users /var/run/crond.pid` fails with below error 
`chgrp: cannot access '/var/run/crond.pid': No such file or directory` @raoslaw

Comment: @MajorXbox Shieeet :( I didn't occur to me that this file is created dynamically. Well, you can always to the same for folder  `/run` instead of file. But remember to do it on `/run` because `/var/run` is only linked to this folder (at least in my case).

Comment: `/var/run` is linked in my case too. But `chgrp` on `/run` didnt work either.

Comment: @MajorXbox please look at the edit. For me, your case works fine. I'm afraid I cannot reproduce.

Comment: If you see, there is no `crond` process started even though it is in `entrypoint.sh`. To see the error, try `docker run` without `-d`. --> build: `docker build -t crond:1 .` --> run: `d run -it --name crond crond:1`

Comment: @MajorXbox I feel stupid now. I was expecting an error during container run process. Anyways I was thinking `crond` has to invoke commands on behalf of other users. How could it do that without being run by `root`? Even if somehow you will run this demon process with this user there is a high probability that it will lack other permissions in order to run certain commands.

Comment: you are right on `crond` needing other permissions. Also tried daemon process and starting process on restart commands with same errors. Anyways, I moved away from using `crond`. Thanks for checking this out.

Answer (score -2):

How about build again according with [OpenShift Container Platform-Specific Guidelines](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines)
 ? Such as related uid and gid.