# Kubernetes: How to run a script with different user from root

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I'm facing an issue on executing a cronjob.Below is the snippet of the code.

```
 containers:
      - name: ssm1db
        image: anuragh/ubuntu:mycronjob5
        imagePullPolicy: Always
       command:
         - "/bin/sh"
         - "-c"
         - "kubectl exec ssm1db-0 -- bash -c 'whoami; /db2/db2inst1/dba/jobs/dbactivate.sh -d wdp'"
```

For example.
I'm able to execute the below code .Here db2inst1 is the user which i need the script to be executed.

```
/bin/su -c ./full_online_backup.sh - db2inst1
```

But while executing using kubectl ,getting below error

```
/bin/su: /bin/su: cannot execute binary file
command terminated with exit code 126
[root@ssm1db-0 /]#
```

Comment: Could someone please help me on this

Comment: If a command is found but is not executable, the return status is 126. [Refer](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) .. So does your user have execute permissions for what you are trying ?

Comment: @AnuraghRavindran what is the exact command you wanna run with the cronjob. And the other thing I see in here is, you are using relative paths like ./full_online... can you try with absolute paths?

Comment: @Anuragh Ravindran Could you please provide the answers to above questions?

Answer (score 0):

Related question : [How to start crond as non-root user in a Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103621/how-to-start-crond-as-non-root-user-in-a-docker-container)

You would encounter permission issues when running crond in a non root user.