# Error while running crontab as non root docker users

Tags: linux, docker, cron, containers, centos7

I have a centos7 docker container which is running as non root user. I installed cronie and started crond as non root user from the containers entrypoint.sh

entryoint.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sleep 2h
```

I login to the container and manually run the crontab in debug mode as

```
    crond -x ext
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
RUN groupadd rsuser -g 10001
RUN useradd -d /home/rsuser -m rsuser -u 10001 -g 10001 -p rsuser
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
RUN yum install -y cronie && yum clean all
RUN touch /var/run/crond.pid
RUN echo '* * * * * root echo "crontab running"' >> /etc/crontab
RUN setcap cap_setgid+ep /usr/sbin/crond && \
    setcap cap_setuid+ep /usr/sbin/crond
RUN chown -R rsuser:rsuser /var/run/crond.pid
RUN chmod 400 /etc/shadow
USER 10001
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

If I run crontab commands as root then I get below error

```
* * * * * root echo "crontab running"
log_it: (CRON 23) ERROR (setgid failed): Operation not permitted
```

If I run crontab commands as rsuser then I get below error

```
* * * * * rsuser echo "crontab running"
log_it: (CRON 23) ERROR (initgroups failed): Operation not permitted
```

Not finding a way to fix that.

Comment: Also posted in https://forums.docker.com/t/error-while-running-crontab-as-non-root-docker-users/111633

Comment: Can you check out [Raoslaw's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53104274/2074820) answer to similar question.